# Верна ли пунктуация в моем следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

«Остается лишь надеяться, что, если не в одежде, так хоть в настроении, вы предпочтете светлые тона».

Смущает запятая после «настроении», нужна ли она там?..

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134270/discussion-on-question-by-flossyu-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Остается лишь надеяться, что если не в одежде, так хоть в настроении вы предпочтете светлые тона.**

Либо:

**Остается лишь надеяться, что — если не в одежде, так хоть в настроении — вы предпочтете светлые тона.** (Вместо тире могут быть запятые, как у вас, — что, на мой взгляд, нежелательно, потому что возникает визуальная путаница между тремя запятыми, — или скобки.)

Comment: Первый вариант. Да. Я так же думала.

Comment: @flossyU  Остается только принять правильный ответ, но мне кажется, что вы вообще перестали их принимать.  Вот только не могу понять почему.

Comment: Приняла. Я думала, прием ответа - это треугольничек наверх.

Answer (score 2):

**Об обособлении оборота** (дополнение к дискуссии **наших участников** в качестве **размышления**)

Вот предложение: *Остается лишь надеяться, что (в чем?) **если не в одежде, так хоть в настроении** вы предпочтете светлые тона.*

Почему бы нам не сделать его **грамматический разбор**?

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным. В состав  придаточного  входит **обстоятельственный оборот**, состоящий из **двух однородных членов** (в одежде, в настроении), связанных **двойным союзом** ЕСЛИ НЕ…ТАК ХОТЬ.

Оборот входит **в основное сообщение**,  и обособлять его  (выделять, актуализировать) особого смысла нет. К тому же при обособлении мы получаем **избыток запятых**, что не способствует ясному пониманию конструкции.

Обособление **двумя тире** тоже нежелательно – так мы получим **вставную конструкцию**, передающую дополнительную информацию. У нас же это информация первого плана.

И вывод: обособление обстоятельственного оборота **не требуется.**

Казалось бы, все ясно, **однако нет.** Как известно, истина относительна – как и всякая аксиома, она верна **в определенных пределах**.

Удалось ли нашим участникам их обозначить – вот в чем вопрос, и это наши читатели, вероятно, должны решить сами.

Comment: У нас речь шла о том, может ли быть контекст, при котором информация первого плана станет дополнительной.

Comment: А кто  поставил перед вами такую  странную задачу, какой в ней смысл? И что  же решили?

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы доказать: вариант с обособлением и вариант без обособления — разные варианты и оба правильные.

Comment: Понятно. Нужно было оправдать обособление оборота тире, а для этого подобрать соответствующий контекст (или даже два контекста).  И как, получилось, результаты можно опубликовать?  Кто победил, или у вас ничья?

Comment: Вы же заявили свой комментарий как "дополнение дискуссии в качестве итога". Как вы собрались подвести итог, если не поняли, чем там в дискуссии дело закончилось? :)

Comment: Ладно, я ответ поправлю. А вы пока подготовьте итоговые материалы, уж очень интересно контекст увидеть.

Comment: пусть oleedd подготавливает, если хочет.

Comment: Он не хочет, потому что спит.  Короче, все с вами ясно. Вероятно, это особый жанр спора, где важно не само действие (содержание), а театральноть, эффектность, зрелищность.  А сколько новых слов можно узнать! Возможно, зрители ночного театра остались довольны.

Comment: В споре рождается истина. Иногда, правда, приходится проводить кесарево. А бывает и выкидыш.

Comment: Да ладно, что это вас в медицину потянуло. Пжста, приводите нам красивые, эстетически приятные сравнения. Я вот, напротив, в качестве театрального обозревателя, даю положительную оценку спектаклю. Главное в любой области жизни (и в споре тоже) – это получить удовольствие.

Comment: у меня иное мнение о главном в жизни. Но ладно.

Comment: Иметь другое мнение о главном в жизни – это тоже удовольствие.